# If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\cdot b_n=0$ then either $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0$ or both.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove or disprove: 
If $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\cdot b_n=0$ then either $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0$ or both.

The answers say it is not necessarily true. I can't find a counter example, however. Would appreciate your reply.

Comment: Do limits of $a_n,b_n$ exist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $a_n = 0$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n=1$ if $n$ is even and take $b_n = 1$ if $n$ is odd and $b_n=0$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 8):

Let $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd and $1$ if $n$ is even and $b_n=1$ if $n$ is odd and $0$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

If at least one sequence has a limit, then it *is* true.

Proof: Without loss of generality, let $a_n$ have a limit. If the limit is zero, it is done. If the limit is nonzero, without loss of generality assume it is a positive value $m$. From some point onwards, $a_n$ would have only positive terms. Assume that $b_n$ doesn't have limit $0$, so it must have infinitely many terms at least some distance (call it $k$) from $0$. For arbitrarily large $n$, the product would have absolute value at least $km - \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon$ tending to $0$. Therefore, $b_n$ must have limit $0$.